# ASP.Net Google Calendar API v3: Multiple Events with the same ID

Tags: asp.net, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using the Google API v3 to fetch the calendars of users and let them create/edit events for their calendars. On some instances, I noticed that newly created events had the same event ID after being posted via thr API. 
Here is an example of two different events with the same ID: 
[image: Two different events with the same ID]

Since the event IDs are assigned by Google, I don't understand how this can happen. I am using these event IDs as IDs for my controls, so they break my application when they are duplicate. Can anybody shed some light on to why this is happening?

Comment: is it a recurring event?

Comment: No, not recurring. 
This problem happens randomly for my users and the only way to solve it atm is to have them delete one of the problematic events. If you use the Google calendar app, you can see both events.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? How are you fetching these events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out: an event can pe part of multiple calendars. For example, a user can have the event "Feed the dog" in the calendar "Personal" and also in the calendar "General". When populating a control that displays both calendars, you get this event 2 times. 
My solution was to use event ID and calendar ID as unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is that these are the same event (likely for two different attendees). Event IDs are only unique within a calendar. To have global uniqueness, you need to use calendar id + event id.

It could also happen that the same event shows up on multiple pages when listing but that does not seem to be the case.